# can't access keyspace in cql created in cli

Tags: java, cassandra

I created a keyspace with the cassandra-cli tool, and i can "use" it.  However when I go try to use the cqlsh command to "use" the keyspace, it doesn't exist.  Can I not use them both?

Comment: Posting an example of your create and use statements as well as the error would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using cassandra 1.1.1 and I never face this kind of issue; 
Check if your cqlsh client is pointing to your cassandra server (open the cqlsh file and see if "DEFAULT_HOST" points to your cassandra server). It may help

Answer (score 8):

If you used uppercase as name for Your Keyspace, you'll have to use quotes:
use "Twissandra"
The same for the column family:
select * from "User";

Answer (score 0):

This is very curious indeed... I have just experienced a similar behavior. What I noticed was that cqlsh "does not like" CamelCase names. I had multiple keysets, and it did not allowed me to "use" any of them, only the ones without CamelCased names... I made a simple experiment of creating a keyspace with only lower cases from cassandra-gui, and then access it from cqlsh, and it worked perfectly. Not sure exactly why this happens, but it works.